# .map an array so that it only keeps the first 5 characters of each element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the .map function change this array so that I only have the first 5 characters, like "01:00", "02:00"?

Here's the array:

```
["01:00:00 AM", "02:00:00 AM", "03:00:00 AM", "04:00:00 AM", "05:00:00 AM", "06:00:00 AM", "07:00:00 AM", "08:00:00 AM", "09:00:00 AM", "10:00:00 AM", "11:00:00 AM", "12:00:00 PM", "13:00:00 PM", "14:00:00 PM", "15:00:00 PM", "16:00:00 PM", "17:00:00 PM", "18:00:00 PM", "19:00:00 PM", "20:00:00 PM", "21:00:00 PM", "22:00:00 PM", "23:00:00 PM", "00:00:00 AM"]
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Do you know how to do it for a single string?

Answer (score 2):

First define a function to grab the first 5 characters of a string:

```
function first5(str){return str.substring(0, 5)}
```

then pass that **function** to array.map:

```
arr = ["01:00:00 AM", "02:00:00 AM", "03:00:00 AM"]  // you can use your full array here
arr.map(first5) //=> ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00"]
```

if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for array.map, it (like many other functions in javascript) takes a function as input.